# selecting an Image from input type=file and setting it as a background using styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

My goal is to select an image using the input type=file tag and setting that image as a background.
Basically, I have a `<div>` and inside that `<div>` I have `<input>` tag, Im using react styled-components for this. So that when onchange event listener gets fire it saves the image in my state and use it to pass it down as a prop to my  styled-component. What I want is if my state = null set div's background to a linear-gradient background if state = image set that image as a background.

The problem: the image is not setting as a background and also how set background to linear-gradient if state = null?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";


export default function Pic1() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);

  const handleOnchange = (e) => {
    const file = Array.from(e.target.files);
    const backgroundImage = file[0].name;

    setImg(backgroundImage);
    
  };

  console.log(img);
  return (
    <>
      <Pic1Container img={img} >
        <Input type="file" onChange={handleOnchange}/>
      </Pic1Container>
    </>
  );
}

const Pic1Container = styled.div`
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #ff9a9e 0%,
    #fad0c4 99%,
    #fad0c4 100%
  );
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.img}) ;
  border: 10px solid white;
  background-size: cover;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  opacity: 0;
  width: calc(20vw - 20px);
  height: calc(30vh - 20px);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
`;
```

Comment: hi, what is the problem?

Comment: hey, thank you forgot that part lol, but just edited it. problem: image is not setting as background after selecting it from input type=file